# Show that annihilator of subspace $U$ is isomorphic to orthogonal complement of $U$ on an inner product space of finite dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $U\leq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that for $U^{\bot}$ being the annihilator of $U$, e.g. $U^{\bot}$ is in the dual space $\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^*$:
$$U^{\bot} \cong \mathcal{A} = \{ v\in\mathbb{R}^n \lvert v\in ker(l_u) \quad \forall u \in U \}$$
Where $l_u(v) = \langle u,v \rangle$

My approach was working with a basis $B=(u_1, \ldots, u_m)$ of $U$ that we can expand to a basis $(u_1, \ldots, u_m, v_1, \ldots, v_{n-m})$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $U^{\bot}$ is of dimension $n-m$ and there exists a basis $(w_1, \ldots, w_{n-m})$ of $U^{\bot}$.

We notice that for all $1\leq i\leq m:$ $u_i \notin ker(l_u) \forall u \in U$ since $l_{u_i}(u_i) = {u_{i_1}}^2 + \ldots + {u_{i_n}}^2 > 0$, so the dimension of $\mathcal{A}$ can be at most $n-m$.
Is there a way to go on and show $dim_{\mathbb{R}} \mathcal{A}$ is in fact $n-m$ hence $U^{\bot} \cong \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Just observe that $u\mapsto\langle u,-\rangle$ is a natural isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ which maps the orthogonal complement of $U$ onto the annihilator of $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annihilator of $U$, denoted by $\mathcal{A}$, is defined by
$$\mathcal{A}=\{f\in \left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^*|f(u)=0 \ \text{for all} \ u\in U\}.$$
Let $\dim_\mathbb{R}(U)=m$. We will prove that
$$\dim_\mathbb{R}(\mathcal{A})=n-m.$$

Let $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ be a basis of $U$. By basis extension, we construct a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$: $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m,v_{m+1},\ldots,v_n\}$. Let $\{f_1,\ldots,f_m,f_{m+1},\ldots,f_n\}$ be a basis of  $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$.  We will show that $\{f_{m+1},\ldots,f_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathcal{A}$.

Note that $\{f_{m+1},\ldots,f_n\}$ is linearly independent, because $\{f_1,\ldots,f_m,f_{m+1},\ldots,f_n\}$ is a basis of  $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$. Thus, we only need to show that $\{f_{m+1},\ldots,f_n\}$ spans $\mathcal{A}$.

Since that $\mathcal{A}$ is a subspace of $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, then every $g\in\mathcal{A}$ can be written as
$$g=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i,$$
where $a_1,\ldots a_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ is a basis of $U$, we can show that
\begin{align}
g(u_1)=0\Rightarrow& \sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(u_1)=0\Rightarrow a_1=0;\\
g(u_2)=0\Rightarrow& \sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(u_2)=0\Rightarrow a_2=0;\\
&\vdots\\
g(u_m)=0\Rightarrow& \sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(u_m)=0\Rightarrow a_m=0.
\end{align}
Since $a_1=0,\ldots,a_m=0$, we have
$$g=\sum_{i=m+1}^n a_i f_i\Rightarrow g\in\text{span}(f_{m+1},\ldots,f_n).$$
Therefore, $\{f_{m+1},\ldots,f_n\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\dim_\mathbb{R}(\mathcal{A})=n-m$.

**Edit:**

Now, let $l_u:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined by $l_u(v)=\langle u,v\rangle$, where $u\in U$. The orthogonal complement of $U$, denoted by $U^\perp$, is defined by
$$U^\perp=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n|v\in\ker(l_u) \ \text{for all} \ u\in U\}.$$

Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $U$. By basis extension, we construct an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$: $\{e_1,\ldots,e_m,e_{m+1},\ldots,e_n\}$. Thus, any $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as
$$v=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_m e_m+a_{m+1}e_{m+1}+\cdots+a_n e_n.$$
Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary. Then,
\begin{align}
v=&a_1e_1+\cdots+a_m e_m+v-\left(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_m e_m\right)\\
:=&u+w,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
u:=&a_1e_1+\cdots+a_m e_m;\\
w:=&v-u.
\end{align}
Clearly $u\in U$. We will show that $w\in U^\perp$.

Note that
$$l_u(w)=\langle u,w\rangle=a_1\langle e_1,w\rangle+\cdots+a_m\langle e_m,w\rangle.$$
Since
$$\langle e_j,w\rangle=\langle e_j,v\rangle-\langle e_j,u\rangle=a_j-a_j=0,$$
for each $j=1,\ldots,m$, it follows that $l_u(w)=0$ for all $u\in U$. Therefore, $w\in U^\perp.$

Since $v:=u+w$, where $u\in U$ and $w\in U^\perp$, we conclude that
$$\Bbb{R}^n=U+U^\perp.$$
Now, suppose $x\in U\cap U^\perp$. Then, $x\in U$ and $x\in\ker(l_u)$ for all $u\in U$. It follows that $\langle u,x\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$, which implies that $x=0$. Therefore,
$$ U\cap U^\perp=\{0\}.$$
Since $\Bbb{R}^n=U+U^\perp$ and $U\cap U^\perp=\{0\}$, we have
$$\Bbb{R}^n=U\oplus U^\perp.$$
If $\Bbb{R}^n=U\oplus U^\perp$, then $\dim_\mathbb{R}(\Bbb{R}^n)=\dim_\mathbb{R}(U)+\dim_\mathbb{R}(U^\perp)$. Therefore,
$$\dim_\mathbb{R}(U^\perp)=n-m.$$
Finally, we can conclude that
$$\boxed{\mathcal{A}\cong U^\perp},$$
because $\dim_\mathbb{R}(\mathcal{A})=\dim_\mathbb{R}(U^\perp)$.

Comment: Yes, that is a proof for the dimension of the annihilator being $n-m$. But the one I am missing is the dimension of $\mathcal{A}$ that is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, not $\mathbb{({R}^n})^*$

Comment: @wheeler Please, check my edited answer.